# Configuring Bind 9 for multiple domain

Tags: networking, bind, dns-zone, dns-hosting

Hi I am a newbees with Bind I want to hoste multiple domain on the same name server. I'm not sure about my config can you help me ! here's I supposed the public address of the name server is 10.10.10.10 address

here's how I config :

named.conf

```
options {
     directory "/windows/system32/dns/etc";
     pid-file  "/windows/system32/dns/etc/named.pid";
     recursion no;  
};

zone "aaa.qc.ca" in {
      type master;
      file "db.aaa";
};

zone "bbb.qc.ca" in {
      type master;
      file "db.bbb";
};

zone "ccc.ca" in {
      type master;
      file "db.ccc";
};
zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" in {
      type master;
      file "db.loopback";
};

zone "." {
     type hint;
     file "db.cache";
};
```

here's my db for each zone

db.aaa

```
$TTL 2h
aaa.qc.ca. IN SOA ns1.aaa.qc.ca. hostmaster.aaa.qc.ca. (
                       2017080509   ; Serial yymmddxx
                       7200     ; Refresh 2hours
                       3600     ; Retry 2hours
                       1209600      ; Expire 48hours
                       3600 )       ; Minimum TTL 24hours

                IN NS           ns1.aaa.qc.ca.
            IN NS       ns.xxx.qc.ca.
            IN NS       ns1.yyy.qc.ca.
                        IN MX 10    smtp.aaa.qc.ca.
ns1                     IN A            10.10.10.10
www                     IN A            192.168.0.1
smtp                    IN A            10.10.10.11
;
```

db.bbb

```
$TTL 2h
bbb.qc.ca. IN SOA ns1.bbb.qc.ca. hostmaster.bbb.qc.ca. (
                       2017080511   ; Serial yymmddxx
                       7200     ; Refresh 2hours
                       3600     ; Retry 2hours
                       1209600      ; Expire 48hours
                       3600 )       ; Minimum TTL 24hours

                IN NS           ns1.bbb.qc.ca.
            IN NS       ns.xxx.qc.ca.
            IN NS       ns1.yyy.qc.ca.
            IN MX 10    smtp.bbb.qc.ca.
ns1                     IN A            10.10.10.10
www         IN A        192.168.0.2
smtp1           IN A        10.10.10.11
;
```

db.ccc

```
$TTL 2h
ccc.ca. IN SOA ns1.ccc.ca. hostmaster.ccc.ca. (
                       2017080510   ; Serial yymmddxx
                       7200     ; Refresh 2hours
                       3600     ; Retry 2hours
                       1209600      ; Expire 48hours
                       3600 )       ; Minimum TTL 24hours

                IN NS           ns1.ccc.ca.
            IN NS       ns.xxx.qc.ca.
            IN NS       ns1.yyy.qc.ca.
            IN MX 10    smtp.ccc.ca.
ns1                     IN A            10.10.10.10
smtp            IN A        10.10.10.11
www         IN A        192.168.0.3
;
```

It's is Ok or I make a mistake  thanks

Answer (score 0):

Well, there i no entry for main domain and better make www as `CNAME` for main domain e.g. for `ccc.ca.`:

```
@         IN     A        192.168.0.3
www       IN     CNAME    @
```

Also, there is no SPF and DKIM entries.